# Laravel 5 - O-Auth

Tags: php, facebook, oauth-2.0, laravel-5.1

There is a huge lack of documentation when it comes to using O-Auth and Laravel 5.* it would be great to have a sort of documentation on how to implement it/ get more from it. Some simple stuff like using socialite with guzzle 6.0 throws back an error and it needs downgrading to 4.0 took me nearly a whole day to find.

Currently i have learnt how to make requests to a page but errors are flying in left right and center and there is no 1 place to go for them, after hours of searching i decided it would be a good idea to make a stack overflow question about it since most of the pros live here.

**The problem**

```
ClientException in RequestException.php line 67: Client error response [url]
https: "Big ass URL goes here"  [status code] 400 [reason phrase] Bad Request.
```

I make a request to facebook using the method in the official laravel docs and i get a page with the $user array back, when i refresh this callbackURL page it returns this error. Why is this happening?

Bare in mind this only happens when i refresh the page, initially its fine and i can use the `$user` variable to pull user details.

Comment: I'm sure you will be delighted to find out that Laravel accepts documentation submissions: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/contributions

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going through these all cryptic things, Laravel makes the process of OAuth much easy. Well as you are using Laravel 5, my answer would be most probably to use [Socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite). You can find the [documentation here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#social-authentication).